# How to find size of ArrayList<String> in my map?

Tags: java

I want to find the size of each value from the key-value pair in `Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>>`. Simply writing `list.size()` does not work.

Here's my code:

```
public void getF() throws Exception {
  BufferedReader br2 =
     new BufferedReader(
         new FileReader("/home/abc/NetBeansProjects/network1.txt"));

  System.out.println("hello" +r.usr);

  while ((s= br2.readLine()) != null) {
    String F[]= s.split(":");

    for (String uid : F) {
      if (uid == F[0]) {
        user.add(uid);   
      } else {
        li = followee.get(Integer.valueOf(F[0]));

        if (li == null) {
          followee.put(Integer.valueOf(F[0]), li= new ArrayList<String>());
        }

        li.add(uid);
      }

      System.out.println(followee);
      int g = li.size();
      System.out.println("g:" +g);

      [...]
    }
  }
}
```

Why am I not getting correct size on last line?

Comment: You are assigning Li to a new arraylist inside the if which has 0 size. I suspect the map key is returning null

Comment: What do you mean by does not work ?

Comment: You code looks ok, what is not working ??

Comment: i mean its returning wrong value. for a key value there is 15 values but its returning 2, the number of keys

Comment: @user3104437 please post your full code so it will be more clear to me

Comment: i have edited the code. this is the full code. I want the size of list which i need to use further in my code

Comment: @user3104437 `if(uid == F[0])` don't compare String values using `==`. Use `equals()`.

Comment: Can you post the contents of the file you're reading or add a working example on [ideone](http://ideone.com/) for instance?

Answer (score 1):

Try to follow the data structures, by keeping the variable as close to their usage.
*(I know in other languages the convention is to declare them at the top.)*
Here `li` should be kept at the begin of a while-step. And its more natural to handle `f[0]` outside the loop, instead of `for+if`. I think the latter put you on the wrong foot.

```
    Set<String> user = new HashSet<>(); 
    Map<Integer, List<String>> followee = new HashMap<>();
    String s;
    while ((s = br2.readLine()) != null) {
        // s has the format "key:value value value"
        String keyAndValues[] = s.split(":", 2);
        if (keyAndValues.length != 2) {
            continue;
        }
        Integer key = Integer.valueOf(keyAndValues[0]);
        String values = keyAndValues[1];
        user.add(keyAndValues[0]);

        List<String> li = followee.get(key);
        if (li == null) {
            li = new ArrayList<>();
            followee.put(key, li);
        }
        Collections.addAll(values.split(" +");

        System.out.println(followee);
        int g = li.size();
        System.out.println("g:" + g);
        //[...]
    }
```

Comment: same output as earlier.g=1.

Comment: How does `s` look, isn't that the question? Maybe `s.split("\\:")`?

Comment: Might `s` maybe look like `123: aaa, bbb, ccc` needing `String fa[] = s.split(": *", 2); String fb[] = fa[1].split(", *")`?

Comment: S is 54767:232 89676790 54543 6565 87878